# Fixing dynamic unknown named parameters

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

In this snippet below which is used only as a SELECT statement for multiple rows of data, it gives a error on `$stmt->bind_param($types, ...$values);`:

> mysqli_stmt::bind_param() does not accept unknown named parameters

I understand the error in general, but `$Query` is dynamic with the necessary question marks already in it but may have any number of `$types` and `$values` or maybe only one.

```
$results_array = [];
if (!empty($values)) :
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($Query);
    $stmt->bind_param($types, ...$values);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()) :
        $results_array[] = $row;
    endwhile;
    $stmt->close();
    return $results_array;
endif;
```

`$mysqli` of course contains the connection string while `$Query` is the dynamic query being used which already contains the question marks and `$types` contains the related field types, ie "sssi" or whatever and matches the data in the `$values` array.

It seems to be working now thanks to the help below. Since some of this came from the answers and comments, I can't take credit for so I'll append what I have now here as the current problem appears to have been solved! I also elaborated on it a bit. This is a small part of a much larger function so $selType is being passed into it.

```
$results_array = [];
if (!empty($values)) :
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($Query);
    $stmt->bind_param($types, ...$values);
    $stmt->execute(array_values($values));
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    if ($selType === "assoc") :
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) :
            $results_array[] = $row;
        endwhile;
    else :                  
        while($row = $result->fetch_array()) :
            $results_array[] = $row;
        endwhile;
    endif;
    $stmt->close();
    return $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all();
 endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically generate the question marks for the SQL query based on the number of values, and then bind the values to the parameters with `mysqli_stmt::bind_param()`

After refactoring your code, it should look like this.

```
$results_array = [];
if (!empty($values)) {
    $num_values = count($values);
    $question_marks = str_repeat("?,", $num_values);
    $question_marks = rtrim($question_marks, ",");
    $Query .= " VALUES (" . $question_marks . ")";

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($Query);
    $stmt->bind_param($types, ...$values);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
        $results_array[] = $row;
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
return $results_array;
```

Comment: Thank you and great answer that will be quite helpful but I'm not sure that's the problem in this case. The queries already have the question marks already in place.

Comment: You could also just pass the values as an array in `execute`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to unpack an associative array. It needs to be a list instead. You can just use `array_values` to convert it into a list.

Your code simplified on PHP 8.1 should look like this:

```
$results_array = [];
if (!empty($values)) :
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($Query);
    $stmt->execute(array_values($values));
    return $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all();
endif;
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253057/discussion-on-answer-by-dharman-fixing-dynamic-unknown-named-parameters); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.